# R Creating a new variable name by partially matching other variable names

Tags: r, string-matching

I would like to create a new variable `x` if there is an `a` or `A` in any of the other variable names with the following sample:

```
structure(list(A = 10L, a = 20L, abc = 1L), .Names = c("A", "a", "abc"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

The result should look like this:

```
structure(list(A = 10L, a = 20L, abc = 1L, x = 31L), .Names = c("A", "a", 
"abc", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

I attempted to accomplish this via:

```
names1$x[grep("a" | "A", colnames(names1))]
```

The following error resulted:

> "Error in "a" | "A" : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

I also tried to only match `a` but this resulted in `NULL`.

Comment: Try `if (grep("a|A", colnames(names1))) names1$x<-31`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `which` and `grepl` to get the indices which match the "A|a" requirement.

In my code, I've added in an element `b`, just to show that `b` is not summed over. I've copied your code apart from that.

```
input <- structure(list(A = 10L, a = 20L, abc = 1L, b = 3L), .Names = c("A", "a", "abc", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

> input
   A  a abc b
1 10 20   1 3
```

Then we can do:

```
input$x <- sum(input[which(grepl("a|A",names(input)))])

> input
   A  a abc b  x
1 10 20   1 3 31
```

Note how `b` is not summed over.

Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: Thanks is there a way to completely avoid having to enter each possible variation of the different cases in order to obtain the same result? I have several hundred variables with string names, where I'll have to combine 5-10 of them that contain some form of a single word (e.g., word can occur in different places, in upper or lower case, etc.) into a single variable. I know that I would have to specify any alternate spellings but am hoping not to have to specify every permutation of upper or lower case at least. Many thanks.

Comment: I also have a lot of missing data which seems to result in NA when I use the coding above.

Comment: Hrmm, I think your best bet would be to post a new question, but include a much larger chunk of your data - make sure you include a chunk which has missing data in it too. Without being able to see your data, the variables you'd like to use, and your expected output, it is quite difficult to help.